# System Initiated IVR Call to trap Voice Response

Tags: twilio, ivr

I need to make an IVR app in php where the syetm initiates the outbound call and traps a voice response from user.

How may i go about doing this?

This is my code (does not trap response from user)

****voice.xml contents****

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- page located at http://example.com/complex_gather.xml -->
<Response>
</Response>
```

**completed.php contents**

```
file_put_contents('voice.txt',$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

**Main Code**

```
<?php
 
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Twilio\Rest\Client;
use Twilio\TwiML\VoiceResponse;


// Find your Account SID and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
// and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
$sid = "xxx";
$token = "xxx";
$twilio = new Client($sid, $token);

$call = $twilio->calls
               ->create("+1310XXXXXXX", // to
                        "+15676777774", // from
                        [
                            "method" => "GET",
                            "statusCallbackMethod" => "POST",
                            "url" => "http://xxxx.com/voice.xml"
                        ]
               );

$response = new VoiceResponse();
$gather = $response->gather(['action' => '/completed.php','method' => 'GET', 'input'=>'speech','timeout'=>3,''=>'true','speech_model'=>'phone']);
$gather->say('Enter something, or not');
echo $response;
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you [create a call through the Twilio API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource#create-a-call-resource), as you are doing, you pass a URL parameter.

When the call connects, Twilio will make a [webhook (HTTP) request](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/webhooks) to that URL and will follow the instructions that are returned in the form of [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml).

Currently your `/voice.xml` endpoint returns an empty `<Response/>` which will cause the call to hang up as there is no TwiML to execute.

Instead of returning an empty `<Response/>` from `/voice.xml` you should return the TwiML you generate at the end of your script.

So, perhaps `voice.xml` should be `voice.php` and look a bit like this:

```php
<?php 
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Twilio\Rest\Client;
use Twilio\TwiML\VoiceResponse;

header('Content-Type: application/xml');

$response = new VoiceResponse();
$gather = $response->gather(['action' => '/completed.php','method' => 'GET', 'input'=>'speech','timeout'=>3,''=>'true','speech_model'=>'phone']);
$gather->say('Enter something, or not');
echo $response;
```

You should also return TwiML from your `completed.php` endpoint too.

```php
<?php
file_put_contents('voice.txt',$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
header('Content-Type: application/xml');
?>
<Response/>
```

Comment: If this was the correct answer, could you please mark it as correct so that others can see that it helped too? Thanks!